# Mongodb query by month

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document like below.

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "name" : "Robin",
    "membership" : [
        {
            "package" : 12,
            "time" : "months",
            "active" : true,
            "start" : ISODate("2017-07-26T09:21:55.360Z")
        },
        {
            "package" : 1,
            "time" : "months",
            "active" : true,
            "start" : ISODate("2017-09-26T09:51:46.915Z")
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 9,
    "name" : "Linh Tran",
    "membership" : [
        {
            "package" : 1,
            "time" : "months",
            "active" : true,
            "start" : ISODate("2017-09-26T09:57:37.638Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to to query membership that start in September. I know there is [$month (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/#exp._S_month) in the Doc but it not cover my case.

Update: Output should contain result where membership start in September. Mean other month like July not show.

Comment: Can you give an example output of what you'd expect?

Answer (score 0):

Run an aggregate operation that first uses the **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#descend)** pipeline to filter at collection level the documents whose membership starts in September as follows:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$or": [
                    "$membership", 
                    { "$eq": [ { "$month":  "$start" }, 9 ] } 
                ] },
                "$$DESCEND",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "name" : "Robin",
    "membership" : [ 
        {
            "package" : 1.0,
            "time" : "months",
            "active" : true,
            "start" : ISODate("2017-09-26T09:51:46.915Z")
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 9,
    "name" : "Linh Tran",
    "membership" : [ 
        {
            "package" : 1.0,
            "time" : "months",
            "active" : true,
            "start" : ISODate("2017-09-26T09:57:37.638Z")
        }
    ]
}
```